Sub-multiplicativity of the growth function of a finetely generated group
I want to show that the growth function of a finetely generated group is Sub-multiplicative. In detail: Let $G$ be a finite and $S$ a finite generating set.
I want to proof that $\forall r,r'\in\mathbb{N}:\beta_{G,S}(r+r')\leq\beta_{G,S}(r)\cdot\beta_{G,S}(r')$
Here $\beta_{G,S}(r)=|B_r^{G,S}(e)|$ denotes the quantity of elements in the closed ball of radius $r$ around $e$ with respect to the word Metric $d_S$ on $G$.
I´ve already tried using the subadditive of the word length, but I´m not sure if that´s the right way and I didn´t seem to get anywhere. Now I´m stuck.
Thank you for your time and help!

A word of length at most $r+r^\prime$ is a word of length at most $r$ concatenated with a word length at most $r^\prime$. That's it.

Thank you very much :)
